# Jenkins, Jenkins SSH Plug-In, EC2, "ubuntu" user and "www-data"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to install Jenkins to achieve a Github -> EC2 instance folder pipeline. So far everything works well when I target an empty folder... however,  when I target my production folder owned by `www-data` the SSH copy of the files fail for permission, as Jenkins uses the `ubuntu` user, the only one I have an SSH login for.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried running the command as another user? (sudo -u)

Comment: Where am I given a chance to issue a command? the SSH is a plug-in to Jenkins, is it not?

Comment: I did not know that you were using the Jenkins SSH plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ssh plugin gives you both options, 
Either send build artifacts to remote server or run a command on the remote server. 
The name of the plugin is "send build artifacts over ssh".. use that

Comment: You mean the [Publish Over SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin)?

Comment: Yes, you can execute commands on remote server too